# Custom Error page for failed application Initialization

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm struggling to find a solution to the following use case.

Our sitecore analytics (DMS) db is out of control and frequently locks up causing sql to generally be unavailable, during these short intervals of errors our custom error pages that we've set up **using the Custom Error node begin to fail because the application pool gets reset and sql is required inside of sitecore's initialize application pipeline.  Can I get out in front of this message?**

Below is the stack trace:

```
       System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline) +175
   Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain.CreateAnonymousUserIfNeeded() +56
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers.Process(PipelineArgs args) +143
   (Object , Object[] ) +80
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +191
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +172
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +516
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475
```

Comment: You really ought to figure out why this is happening and see if you can prevent it in the first place...otherwise you're throwing a band-aid on it and this could escalate to a bigger problem and a longer outage when you least need it (like 3am on Friday night before a holiday weekend)

Comment: I don't disagree, but things aren't always that simple.  While we wait on budget and approvals and upgrades to the mongo db, we'd like to at least put up a page that redirects to another site where they can still purchase

Comment: If the DMS functionality is not used, then maybe consider turning it off.

Comment: Consider archiving Analytics data to a reporting database. I'd also recommend that the Analytics database run on its dedicated hardware if possible.

Comment: it is, but the analytics data is used realtime to make personalized content decisions.  We archive the hell out of it, purge it, etc, it's just bad.  This is one reason they moved to mongo db.

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking a look at the IIS custom errors to capture the 500 instead, that way they are a catch-all and will work if asp net falls over. You can set them either through the IIS manager or in config with the system.webServer/httpErrors elements.

From MSDN: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific error number when this happens, you can handle it in web.config to a page that isn't running out of Sitecore. I think you can also set up a default that will catch any unhandled exception.

Here's the documentaition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
<customErrors>
 <error StatusCode="XXX" redirect="errorpage.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: that is what I'm doing, but it still errors.  since sitecore pipelines still evaluate the request, unless I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: Are you redirecting to a SiteCore aliased URL, or a physical URL to a file that doesn't use any SiteCore functionality? I used to work with Ektron, and the latter was our way to handle errors in the CMS (since if the CMS went down, that page needed to stay up)

Comment: Just saw your edit - try redirecting to an HTML file (which won't execute through .NET unless you've customized your server)

Comment: oh, it was originally html, I tried changing the extension to rerr and specifically excluding it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a web application as opposed to a website most likely is why you're not getting the behavior you think you would.

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx and follow the global.asax approach, which get the redirect firing in the right place in the right stack.